# Как сделать чтобы было видно 50% с правой стороны?

Tags: css

[image]

```
.slider__img2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/img2.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: -80px;
    background-position: 25px, 0px;
}
```

Comment: width : 100% так?

Comment: или чтобы отображалась только правая часть?

Comment: @user355827 да только правая часть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider__img2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  background-image: url(https://rat.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1873-Business-Cat-300x288.png); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}


.slider__img2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;  
  background-size: 200%;
  background-image: url(https://rat.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1873-Business-Cat-300x288.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.slider__img2:hover:after{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__img2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

И еще один пример

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 70%, blue 70%);
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/401063/10ea759c-e425-4551-9f38-12354c89fde6/s1200?webp=false") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 35%;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 56%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 70%, blue 70%);
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 9px -5px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: width 1s ease;
}

div:hover:before {
  width: 0%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```